# Cgi script wont refresh form

Tags: apache, bash, cgi

I'm writing a cgi script using Bash and this form submitted the url for my form and now it won't refresh even if I change the code to take less queries.

```
echo '<form method=GET action="AddStudent.sh?a=Fname&b=Lname&c=Jdate&d=Lpay&e=Add&f=Pname&g=Pphone">'
```

When I changed it to this it still submitted a as Fname and not Tname

```
echo '<form method=GET action="AddStudent.sh?a=Tname&b=Lname&c=Jdate&d=Lpay&e=Add&f=Pname&g=Pphone">'
```

when I changed it to this, the url still contained the previous queries.

```
echo '<form method=GET action="AddStudent.sh?a=Tname">'
```

Is it an issue with my browser, apache setup, or code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query string you specify on the action URL is dropped and replaced by the form contents because you use GET. If you didn't change anything in the actual form elements, this results in identical GETs to the same URL, which will be cached by your browser.

The solution would be to add the parameters as form elements instead, and perhaps add a 'Cache-Control: no-cache' header if you plan on submitting the same values with GET over and over.

Comment: The issue is I have this dropdown list which gets Tname that was not being submitted:  

echo '<span>'
echo '<select>'
while read -r line
do
name=`echo $line | sed 's/ /%20/'`
  echo '<option name="Tname" value='$name'>'$line'</option>'
done <"/var/www/teachers"
echo '</select>'
echo '</span>'

I added what you said about Cache-Control and its not working...

Comment: The name attribute should go on the select element, not on option.